# Create query to select makers that make more printers than pc\laptops

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, datatable, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I'm new with SQL Queries and I'm learning with Oracle in livesql.oracle. I have this db and I need to Create query to select makers that make more printers than pc\laptops. The makers attribute is on the Product table only and the attribute in common with all tables is model. Tables info:

```
table Laptop (serial_number varchar(50),
 model,
 price,
 speed,
 ram,
 hd,
 screen,
 CONSTRAINT laptop_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
 CONSTRAINT laptop_2_product_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (model)
 REFERENCES Product(model)); 

table Product (model varchar(50),
 maker,
 type,
 CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (model));

table Printer (serial_number varchar(50),
 model,
 price,
 color,
 type,
 CONSTRAINT printer_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
 CONSTRAINT printer_2_product_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (model)
 REFERENCES Product(model));

table PC (serial_number varchar(50),
 model,
 price,
 speed,
 ram,
 hd,
 cd,
 CONSTRAINT pc_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),
 CONSTRAINT pc_2_product_fk
 FOREIGN KEY (model)
 REFERENCES Product(model));

table Storage (storage_id varchar(50),
 model,
 serial_number,
 transfered_to);
```

All I could manage to do is select the maker that does printers but not laptops. Maybe I should made something similar for the laptop condition and see which makers make more printers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
FROM Product
WHERE type = 'printer'
AND maker NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT maker
    FROM Product
    WHERE type = 'laptop'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, "separate" tables are irrelevant because everything you need to know is contained in the `product` table: it contains makers as well as *hardware* type (whether something is a printer, a laptop or whatever else).

With sample data as:

```
SQL> select * from product order by type, maker, model;

MODEL       MAKER      TYPE
----------- ---------- -------
Dell LP 1   Dell       laptop
Dell LP 2   Dell       laptop
HP LP 1     HP         laptop
Dell PC 100 Dell       pc
HP PC 100   HP         pc
Dell PR 200 Dell       printer
Dell PR 201 Dell       printer
Dell PR 202 Dell       printer
Dell PR 203 Dell       printer
HP PR 300   HP         printer

10 rows selected.
```

Query uses conditional aggregation (in a CTE), while final `select` returns maker(s) that produce more printers than PC/laptops:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select maker,
  3       sum(case when type = 'printer'         then 1 else 0 end) cnt_printer,
  4       sum(case when type in ('laptop', 'pc') then 1 else 0 end) cnt_laptop_pc
  5     from product
  6     group by maker
  7    )
  8  select *
  9  from temp
 10  where cnt_printer > cnt_laptop_pc;

MAKER      CNT_PRINTER CNT_LAPTOP_PC
---------- ----------- -------------
Dell                 4             3

SQL>
```